# I'm getting corrupted files with getObjectCommand() from @aws-sdk/client-s3 V3

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to download with Node.js (Electrum.js) some file from an S3 bucket to my PC,
The problem happen randomly, some pdf files are downloaded correctly, few are corrupted.
My code is really simple, I need some help on how to dig deeper and find the cause of this issue.

```
const downloadEachObject = async (files) => {
  let lastFile;
  const basePath = '/Users/downloadTestDir';
  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const file = files[i];
      if (file.Key === lastFile) {
        continue;
      }
      lastFile = file.Key;
      const fileParams = {
        Bucket: 'bucket',
        Key: lastFile,
      };
      const objData = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(fileParams));
      const subDirectories = file.Key.split('/');

      const newFilePath = path.join(basePath, file.Key);
      const newPdfFile = await objData.Body.pipe(
        fs.createWriteStream(newFilePath)
      )
        .on('error', (error) => {
          console.error('error on createWriteStream: ', error);
        })
        .on('finish', () => {
          console.log('The file has been written to disk ', file.Key);
          // const freeMemory = os.freemem();
          // console.log(`Free memory: ${freeMemory / 1024 / 1024} MB`);
        });
    }
  } catch (er) {
    console.log('error looping trough objects', er);
  }
};
```

I'm sure the parameters are correct and the S3 files path are retrieved with the

> ListObjectsV2Command(bucketParams);

I've also checked directly on the S3 bucket the files are not corrupted.

Comment: @k-j by "directly" I meant via aws console

Comment: @k-j anyway you were right I missed to wrap the fs.createWriteStream() in a promise. Thx for the help.